# error: ‘i’ does not name a type with auto

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++,here is my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>  

int main(){

static const double arr[] = {16.0,2.2,77.5,29.0,24.0};
std::vector<double> vec (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );

std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(),bind2nd(std::minus<double>(), 3.0)); 

for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << ' ';

}
```

When I try to compile with g++ p1.cpp -o p1

```
p1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
p1.cpp:14:11: error: ‘i’ does not name a type
 for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
```

I know that there more ways to print the vector,but why is this not working?

Answer (score 15):

You should try with `-std=c++11` .
Works fine after that.

```
./p1
13 -0.8 74.5 26 21
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if your compiler does not support c++11, use `std::vector<double>::iterator` instead of `auto`.